# Checking if a date is of the same calendar day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar

Could someone please help me figure out how to check if some date is of the same day as today.  I guess it would require creating a calender day at 0 hour of the same day in the same timezone and checking against that, but so far my attempts have confused me more then anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSCalendar lets you deal with human days. So you could implement a category something like this:

```
@implementation NSDate (IsItToday)
- (BOOL)isToday {
    NSUInteger desiredComponents = NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *myCalendarDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:desiredComponents fromDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:desiredComponents fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return [myCalendarDate isEqual:today];
}
@end
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!!!   Looking at the code, I won't beat myself up over not being able to get it on my own :)

Answer (score -1):

You should take a good read through this [Dates and Times Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183), but something like this should work:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval difference = [today timeIntervalSinceDate:otherDate];
NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
if (difference < secondsPerDay)
{
   //same day as today
}
```

Comment: That checks for 24 hours, not if its the same date

Comment: Your answer is wrong (the question asks for calendar days, not time intervals). Please read the question carefully before telling somebody to rtfm!